# python while loop point system - running slow

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have to simulate a points game where the first person to reach 11 points and win by 2 clear points wins the game

I have used a function to decide who wins a point

```
def simulatePoint(winProbabilityA, winProbabilityB):
    rNumber = random.random()
    if rNumber - winProbabilityA <= 0:
            # A wins the game
            return 0
    elif rNumber - winProbabilityA > 0:
            # B wins the game
            return 1
```

and another one to simulate a game

```
def simulateGame (playerA_winProb, playerB_winProb):
    gameWon = False
    pointsA = 0
    pointsB = 0

    while gameWon == False:
            # Simulate point
            point = simulatePoint(playerA_winProb, playerB_winProb)
            if point == 0:
                    pointsA += 1
            elif point == 1:
                    pointsB += 1

            # Checks for points to be equal to 11
            if (pointsA == 11) and (pointsA - pointsB >= 2):
                    # A wins the game
                    gameWon = True
                    return 0
            elif (pointsB == 11) and (pointsB - pointsA >= 2):
                    # B wins the game
                    gameWon = True
                    return 1
```

This is where i believe i am going wrong, i think the while loop is causing the code to run slow

Any help is greatfully accepted

Comment: Does it run infinitely?

Comment: "Run slow" in what sense? It takes too long to reach 11 points?

Comment: it would take a very long time to output the result

Comment: @Bull It would take an infinity, to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the difference becomes greater than or equal to 2, after they have won more than 11 games. So, the logic should have been like this

```
if (pointsA >= 11) and (pointsA - pointsB >= 2):
...
elif (pointsB >= 11) and (pointsB - pointsA >= 2):
...
```

Comment: ahhhhh my bad, forgot to think of that. Makes sense why the code was taking longer in some cases than in other

Comment: @Downvoter Could you please tell me what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is running infinitely.

Consider: `pointsA` and `pointsB` reach `10` and `10` respectively. Now, no matter what player gets the next point, neither of your terminating conditions will be reached because neither `pointsA` nor `pointsB` will be `11` and up by 2 at the same time. This creates an infinite loop.

You'd probably want to check if `pointsA >= 11` and `pointsB >= 11` instead of `A == 11` and `B == 11`.

Looks like thefourtheye beat me by a bit - he gets my vote.